# Gradle: How can I embedde a mock service to start with my service

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, wiremock

I am new to gradle.Working on a spring-boot application. For my tests I have created a mock service using wiremock and want to use that service for a particular endpoint. The original endpoint address is in the application.yml file and I have created test-application.yml file which has the address of the mock service. In gradle I have created the sourceSet and it works fine.

```
integrationTest {
    java {
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
        srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
    }
    resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources')
}
```

How can I embedde the mock service so that my tests hit the mock service and not the real service?

Comment: are we talking about spring ??

Comment: Yes . its a spring-boot application

Comment: Did you check Spring's documentation about testing?? It is clearly specified how to run integration testing and how to mock components.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html. In your case, most probably using dedicated properties file or/and profile will do the trick.